# JPA: Convert date from one format to another

Tags: java, date, jpa

I am passing an argument of type *DATE*, and I need to compare it with a column in the DB which has the date format `MM-DD-YY: HH:MM:SS`, but I don't need the `HH:MM:SS` to be considered. What sort of JPA query would do this?

Comment: update :  the argument which am passing is "2015-05-04T14:23:00-0700" (String type) and now i need the above date as YYYY-MM-DD and compare it with the DB column which is of type DATE

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Most JPA implementations provide JPQL vendor extensions for YEAR, MONTH, DAY functions and you can compare those. Alternatively use JPA 2.1 "FUNCTION" and specify the native SQL function for extracting the YEAR, MONTH, DAY for that column.

Answer (score 0):

Extract all rows from `<table>` where `<column>` contains '2015-05-07' and an arbitrary time extension:

```
select * from <table> where date(<column>) = '2015-05-07'
```

Answer (score 0):

using @Temporal annotation you can take only date

```
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private java.util.Date date;
```

Comment: errm, he says that the column already has the format including TIME, and this is presumably a query for comparison with that columns values, hence no point in setting something for persistence into that column

Comment: ok if use above annotation then we also remove time stamp  and store only date